# How do I write a combined advanced Gmail filter?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I would like to create a filter in Gmail as:

```
to:@mycompany.com OR from:@mycompany.com
```

However when I attempt to create or edit a filter I am given a form with individual fields and cannot find a way to create a combined filter as above.

Has anybody successfully created such a filter lately and how would I do it?

Comment: Do you men filtering or searching with that criteria?

Comment: 'filtering' means 'message arrived - aplly it a label/archive/delete/forward. So what?

Comment: (*typo: mean) I know what a filter is. You can't create a filter but you can search for `to:@mycompany.com OR from:@mycompany.com`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, you can not create such filters. Create two and use both.
If you really need strict display of only @mycompany.com-related messages in your inbox, either use IMAP and some client, or some Gmail app (there are few for MacOS), or write a greasemonkey script that hides anything without from/to label.

UPD: http://lifehacker.com/276499/build-advanced-gmail-filters-and-persistent-searches -- really neat, thought that just adding e-mails to a list of known words is not good, but didn't know that.

Comment: Ah, so one cannot definitively mix advanced search classifiers in their filter. Looking at http://lifehacker.com/276499/build-advanced-gmail-filters-and-persistent-searches seems to imply this is possible in the "Has words" section...

Comment: If you want to edit your answer with the solution I've provided I'll accept it as the authoritative solution.